# Twig returns true even if not in array (checked field)

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I am probably doing it wrong but I am running through an array of values like this.

```php
    {% for checkboxDataKey, checkboxData in checkbox %}
     <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input checkbox-questionlist" type="checkbox"
            {% if checkboxDataKey in values %} checked {% endif %}
            data-report-id="{{ reportId }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ checkboxDataKey }}" id="{{(name)}}-{{checkboxDataKey}}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="{{(name)}}-{{checkboxDataKey}}">
            {{ checkboxData.answer }}
        </label>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

It is checking if the checkboxDataKey is in the value array. This is working until I add the `different` value to the array (it is named `different`).

```php
 array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(9) "different" }
```

When this is selected the first checkbox is also checked and I cannot find out why, since the value 0 is not in the array.

[image]

When I look at the checkbox row keys
`array(5) { [0]=> int(0) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(3) [4]=> int(4) }` they are integers.

Comment: can you add in your post the content of your `values` var (in the line with the `if` statement) ? I think you have made a mistake with the keys of `checkbox` array and the numeric keys of `values`. We really need to see all vars to help.

Comment: Should work as is, see [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/qjqx1h) - What is the data inside `checkbox`?

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed an PHP problem. When I ran an in_array function it returned an true. So I had to do this, to tackle it.

```php
 foreach ($fields['answers'] as $key => $value) {
            $options[$key] = array_merge($value, ['checked' => in_array((string)$key, $values)]);
        }
```